# I want to hide overflow for small devices. How can i do it?

Tags: css, html

[image: How to remove this line?]

Here i uses bootstrap for responsive. But i need to fix overflow.

Css code is:

```
.border-wrapper {
position: absolute;
height: 4px;
background: #333;
top: 64%;
left: 50%;
width: 51%;
z-index: 0;
transform: translate(-50%,0%);
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: more code required, and why are you doing that?

Comment: Have you tried with [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) ?

Comment: no. i know that media queries can fix this problem. But i want to remove it using overflow or others something

Comment: this is full css:.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.video-wrapper:first-child {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.border-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    background: #333;
    top: 64%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 51vw;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%,0%);
}

Comment: and this is html:  
      <div class="row video-wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="single-video-left">
            <video controls>
              <source src="img/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="single-video-right float-right">
            <video controls>
              <source src="img/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-wrapper"></div>
      </div>